# How to type an input with forwardRef in React 17 and styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am using this approach with another component (Button) and it's working properly and Typescript is already gives me autocomplete for the type of Button, but I can't make it work with an Input.

```js
import { ChangeEvent, ComponentPropsWithoutRef, forwardRef, useState } from 'react'

import { StyledInput } from '@/components/atoms/Input'
import { CallbackState } from '@/constants/functions'

export interface InputProps extends ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'input'> {
  callback?: CallbackState<string>
}

export const Input = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>(({ callback, ...props }, ref) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('')

  const onChangeHandler = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { value } = event.target
    setText(value)
    if (callback) callback && callback(String(text), setText)
  }

  return <StyledInput type="???" value={text} onChange={(event) => onChangeHandler(event)} ref={ref} {...props} />
})

Input.defaultProps = {}

Input.displayName = 'Input'
```

In a correct approach, type="???" will suggest me text, password, textarea ...

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Check whats the StyledInput type... It needs to be defined there

Comment: I am passing InputProps to Styled Input. I forgot to post the code, but that interface is being applied.